# Uncertain Runtime of Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-complexity, cython

I have been working on some code for computing a stochastic function. I have written the code in Cython, but when I analyze the run-time of the code in the cell I get runtimes that are not constant, but grossly vary. More specifically, one iteration of the code gave a runtime of 0.95s but now gives a 4s runtime for the same iteration. Any guidance in understanding this phenomenon would be very much appreciated. I am currently using Windows 1.5 8th Gen.

The code is provided below:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as nc
from libc.math cimport log, sqrt, pi, cos

from random import uniform

def Stochastic(double h, long T, nc.ndarray prime_list) -> double:
    assert T < 10000000000, 'Our prime list does not exceed the value 10^10'
    
    cdef double ret_val = 0.0
    cdef long p = 0
    cdef double upper = 2 * pi
    
    # filter the primes up to and including the value of T
    cdef nc.ndarray primes = prime_list[prime_list <= T]
    
    # iterate over the primes using the specified model 
    for p in primes: 
        ret_val += ( 1/sqrt(p) * cos(uniform(0, upper) - h*log(p)) )
        
    return ret_val
```

With execution in another cell

```
T_val = int(1e6)
prime_num = 'Externally read prime list from txt file'
x = np.arange(-1,1,1/np.round(np.log(T_val)))

start_time = default_timer()
[[Stochastic(h=i, T=T_val, prime_list=prime_num) for i in x]]
print(default_timer() - start_time)
```

Runtimes have been 0.95, 4.6, 2.5, etc

Comment: I've voted to close as lacking an [mre]. If I had to guess: Cython code needs compiling. Jupyter will compile it the first time, or if it's changed, but otherwise uses the existing version. So sometimes you're measuring the compilation process and sometimes not. But without an example, who knows...

Comment: I have expanded on the code as previously requested.

Comment: I've added in the function of p

Comment: I wonder if `pyximport` is causing the problem though, but sometimes stopping to compile something

Comment: Won't be able to explicitly declare prime_list as it relies on reading in a txt file of primes

Comment: Can you see the problem if prime_list is something like `np.array([7]*10**4)`?

Comment: The runtimes still do not stabilize. Since I am filtering the prime list according to the value of **T**, the larger my **T** the more numbers I add. The issue isn't about the speed, as I know with larger values of **T** my runtime will increase - I don't understand why the runtime changes so widely, with the variance growing for more larger **T**.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. You can try to replace `uniform` through 0 in your program and see whether it is due to random numbers. Then just delete `cos` and see whether you still see it. I assume it is due to `cos(uniform)`, cos(x) has different running time depending on x, for some x it is much higher than for others. This is however implementation dependent.